# Jquery slide div one after another in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

i am trying to slide div after another , [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32Vaq/129/) is the working example,

but i am not able to do it in bootstrap,

**Html markup:**

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="text-align:justify">

            <div id="slider_1" class="row loaddiv">
                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <h3> Slide 1</h3>
                    <p>
                        some text
                    </p>
                </div>    
            </div>


            <div id="slider_2" class="row loaddiv">
                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <h3>Slide 2</h3>
                    <p>
                        some text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div> 
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 1;

    var go = setInterval(function () {

        $('#slider_' + i).show('slide', { direction: 'left' },
        1000).delay(4000).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);

        i++;
        if (i == 4) { i = 1 }

    }, 600)

});
</script>
```

i am new to jquery, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make some CSS changes. remove the delay(), it causes the some visual errors, your code is fine.

```
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = 1;

var go = setInterval(function () {

    $('#slider_' + i).show('slide', { direction: 'left' },
    1000).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);

    i++;
    if (i == 4) { i = 1 }

}, 600)

});
```

Comment: still nothing happened, i am trying just load the div on after another and just stop , may i know what css changes i have to make